# How to creating animation videos programmatically ( Java or C ) from pictures

Tags: animation, compression, video-processing, video-encoding

I am creating a animation video for which I have the frame by frame pictures. I want to create a video out of it but only programmatically and not using any tool like MovieMaker, Flash or AdobePremier.

Please let me know if there any apis which can combine these frames and create compressed video in any of the formats like AVI, MPEG-4 etc and which all takes various parameters like BitRate, KeyFrame rate etc into account while doing the compression

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy task. You can use the opencv api. Initialise an iplimage array to the images you wanna include, run a loop till end of array. Load each image with cvloadimage, display it on window. Have a delay of 1/24 sec. And repeat. You can even choose to save this in the numerous formats supported.